# Why DataFrame isn't accessible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use `findpeaks` module. Need to check my peaks and vallies.
Consider the code below:

```py
results = fp.fit(X)
print(results)
```

When I run the code, it shows me a DataFrame as I upload it below:

[image]

But when I want to check or search in the columns, it gives me error.
Consider the code below:

```py
print(results['peak'])
```

And it throws this error:

***KeyError: 'peak'***

For every columns, it throws this error.
How should I do it? I appreciate all answers.

Comment: "When I run the code, it shows me a DataFrame as I upload it below:" No, it does not. It shows you a dictionary that contains an entry where a DataFrame is the value. In the future, for debugging: be sure to examine the output closely (here, it starts with `{'df':` which should be a giveaway), and consider also checking the *type* of your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `results` is a dictionary, of which the dataframe is one value, with the key `'df'`. So to print the `'peak'` column of the dataframe, try this:

```py
print(results['df']['peak'])
```